# How to use 2 footnotes in the same word?

Tags: footnotes

I have this Paragraph and I was wondering if it's possible to do what is underlined in the figure (RED), or if you know how to do this in another way, let me know. Basically the "DOM.Element" is a child of  WEB API. So there are 2 things there. The "DOM" & "Element".

How to use multiple footnotes in this case? Is that a good way of doing it? TBH I haven't seen anything like it before.

[image]

***For the LaTex folks:***

```
As mentioned above, the design is created due to the reference of Cascade Style Sheets (CSS3) in a HyperText Markup Language (HTML5). This will assign different design commands for every 
\textit{
    DOM\footnote{ Document Object Model (DOM) - \url{https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model}}
    .Element\footnote{ Element - \url{https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element}}
}
individually, or in a form of a group using \textit{Element.id} and/or \textit{Element.className}.The benefit of using CSS at this stage is that it loads the styles of the elements before the page loads on the user's screen.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use "DOM element" instead.

"DOM.Element" is not actually a word. It is way used to represent a DOM element in a programming context. In that context it would indeed behave like word and your usage might be correct.

However the sentence or the text is not in that kind of context. If it was you'd have no need to footnote either "DOM" or "Element". This is a general explanation using normal English so you should use normal words and expressions.

Same is true of element id and class. I understand what you are trying here but the text is talking about the general concepts on a very general level not about the specific types in a programming context.

I am guessing that later in the text it gets more technical and that is where the usage comes from?

CSS is from "**Cascading** StyleSheets". Not "Cascade".

Comment: Also the entire first sentence makes no sense at all, and it’s impossible to tell what the antecedent of _this_ in the second sentence is supposed to be (the design, perhaps?). The whole thing is in dire need of editing and proofreading.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "This" refers to the browser reading the referenced CSS and applying it to the document. More or less the entire first sentence. Which refers to "as was explained before" But you are right it is pretty much incomprehensible. I just happened to know what he was trying to explain, so I did not notice. LOL.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. English is not my first language, so all this is new to me. All this now makes a reasonable explanation.